# Passing Data from Silverlight to ASP.NET Page

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, silverlight

I want to pass large amount of information from my silverlight application to an aspx page. What is the preferred or best method to do this?

I can think of the folllowing:

Put it in a temporary table and have the aspx page pick it up from there. Or Pass it in session.

Any help is appreciated

Micky

Comment: "an aspx page" would be that page that is hosting Silverlight or any other in a different web application?

Comment: hosting the silverlight application

Comment: how many Large amount of data you are talking about ?

Comment: What you are suggesting goes against all the principals of Silverlight, so my first question is "What is the actual problem you are trying to solve?"

Comment: You can use javascript and send ajax http request.

Answer (score 2):

I would say, both of your proposals do not work. The Silverlight application runs in the client (browser), how would you store it in session?

I would suggest that you define a service in your web application hosting the Silverlight application and path the data as a parameter. Or you can use HTML file upload to transfer the data.

Edit:
Store large amounts of data in Session is generally not a good idea, depending on the number of users expected on your site (think of DOS attacks as well). If you need to store the data in a database anyway, I would do that from the beginning. I need more information about the use case to give a definite answer.

Comment: I meant that I would write an invoke method to pass the data to the server, store it in session...once the method is completed, I would redirect to aspx page and pick up the data from session

Comment: You mentioned large amount of data and session is not good for that. Unless session is based on database, it can be timeout or destroyed. Using web service is fine idea and may require the same effort as with asp.net page.

Comment: But why do you have to go back? When you post the data to the server you can immediately process it and do not have to store it in Session. What do you want to do with the data?